# Testing for exceptions with [TestCase] attribute in NUnit 3?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, nunit, testcase

**How do I test for exceptions in a TestCase with NUnit3?**

Let's say I have a method `Divide(a,b)` defined as follows:

```
public double Divide(double a, double b)
{
    if(Math.Abs(b) < double.Epsilon) throw new ArgumentException("Divider cannot be 0");
    return a/b;
}
```

I want to test this method using NUnit 3.0 test cases, so maybe I have:

```
[TestCase(-10, 2, -5)]
[TestCase(-1, 2, -0.5)]
public void TestDivide(double a, double b, double result)
{
    Assert.That(_uut.Divide(a, b), Is.EqualTo(result));
}
```

Is there a way to specify a Test Case that will cause Divide() to throw an ArgumentException and somehow have this as the expected result, e.g. something along the lines of:

```
[TestCase(-10, 2, -5)]
[TestCase(-1, 2, -0.5)]
[TestCase(-1, 0, ExpectedResult = TypeOf(ArgumentException)]
public void TestDivide(double a, double b, double result)
{
    Assert.That(_uut.Divide(a, b), Is.EqualTo(result));
}
```

(Of course I could define a separate test method and use `Assert.Throws()` in this, so this is purely out of curiosity)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`ExpectedException` would have been the correct method for NUnit 2.X, but it was removed from NUnit 3.

There's a various snippets of discussion in the [NUnit Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/nunit-discuss) and the equivalent Dev group - but it looks like the decision was made that it's generally a better design pattern to test expected outcomes, and exceptions in separate methods. ([link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/nunit-developer/expectedexception/nunit-developer/Mv8F-dyM7ak/Z5W7zZlvhqkJ))

The only way to do this in NUnit 3, would be to break it down in to two separate tests. (Confirmed in a similar question answered by the NUnit core team, [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/nunit-discuss/ExpectedException/nunit-discuss/mJfGsg8gpN8/SsYD0bWnAgAJ).)

```
[TestCase(-10, 2, -5)]
[TestCase(-1, 2, -0.5)]
public void TestDivide(double a, double b, double result)
{
    Assert.That(_uut.Divide(a, b), Is.EqualTo(result));
}

[TestCase(-1, 0)]
public void TestDivideThrows(double a, double b)
{
    Assert.That(() => _uut.Divide(a, b), Throws.TypeOf<ArgumentException>());
}
```

Comment: If you really wanted to force the two into a single test case, you could add a boolean throwsException argument and test it. However, the presence of an if - then - else and two entirely different expectations would kind of prove that this really should be two different tests.

Comment: "generally a better design pattern to test expected outcomes, and exceptions in separate methods" - I can't update nunit framework on my code without refactoring 1000+ tests because of a "generally better design pattern". That's hardly a nice way of justifying breaking changes

Answer (score 9):

I agree with the Corpus Gigantus's answer but why don't you simplify thing like this:

```cs
[TestCase(-10, 2, -5)]
[TestCase(-1, 2, -0.5)]
[TestCase(-1, 0, null, typeof(ArgumentException))]
public void TestDivide(double a, double b, double result, Type exception = null)
{
    if(exception != null)
    {
        Assert.Throws(exception, delegate { _uut.Divide(a, b);  });
                
    } else Assert.That(_uut.Divide(a, b), Is.EqualTo(result));
}
```

In this way, the expected exception is part of the test parameters as well, note that you can only have two outcome, either the division succeeds or throws.